# ASP.NET MVC 3 deployment error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, ninject

When I run my ASP.NET MVC 3 application with the Ninject it works perfectly, but when I deploy it onto an IIS, it gives this error:

> 

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Betolto.Controllers.DataInputController..ctor() +47
   DynamicInjector7922fd15a4fb4caba8ffb4cc7f18cbcf(Object[] ) +42
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +489
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +177
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) +30
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4222965
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +51
>
[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Betolto.Controllers.DataInputController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +232
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +13
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8969412
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

I've searched through the internet but I've not found the solution to my problem.
I thank for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace the problem is inside your controller's (Betolto.Controllers.DataInputController) constructor.
So NInject is probably working correctly.
My guess is the error arises from something else, a difference between the development and production environment, could be a parameter missing in the configuration file or differences in the database data.
Add logging so you know exactly which line and which object is the null object causing the exception. If you can attach a debugger to your production code that would speed up debugging.

Comment: Thank you. Suddenly the application went wrong in the VS 2010 too but it already gave a cleaner error message: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.".